# Of the given sites, incorrect result being returned

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, struct, conditional-statements

Everything compiles fine and is heavily commented to show what I am trying to accomplish. This [link](https://prnt.sc/s6j4kr) here is an excel spreadsheet to find the highest average wind speed, and then the greatest variation in temperatures. I did this because the results aren't being returned correctly within my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SITE_COUNT 3 // 3 sites 2001,3345,3819
#define DAY_RANGE 7  // 7 days total, between site_ids

typedef struct
{
    int site_id_num;
    int day_of_month; // Day of the month (not used)
    int wind_speed;   
    int temperature;

} measured_data_t;

typedef struct
{
    int site_id_num;  // Storing the correct site ID
    int lowest_temp;  // Storing the lowest temp
    int highest_temp; // Storing the highest temp
    int avg_speed;    // Wind speed, for finding avg wind speed

} calculated_data;

// File pointer
FILE *fptr;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i=0, o=0; // Indexed for loops
    int ARR_SIZ = SITE_COUNT*DAY_RANGE;

    measured_data_t fileData[ARR_SIZ];          // Creates Struct array of 21, for 21 entries, 7 days for 3 sites 
    calculated_data processedData[SITE_COUNT];  // Created Struct array of  3, sites struct array

    // Open File
    if ((fptr = fopen("meteo.txt", "rt")) == NULL)
    {
        // Throw error if no file
        printf("\n Error opening data file");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0; i<ARR_SIZ; i++)
    {
        // Read lines from file, site_id, day, wind speed, temp
        fscanf(fptr, "%d %d %d %d", &fileData[i].site_id_num, &fileData[i].day_of_month, &fileData[i].wind_speed, &fileData[i].temperature);
    }

    for (i=0; i<SITE_COUNT; i++)
    {
        // Assign defaults to processedData
        processedData[i].site_id_num = fileData[i*DAY_RANGE].site_id_num; // site_id_num position in array, 0..7..14
        processedData[i].lowest_temp = -50;
        processedData[i].highest_temp = 50;
        processedData[i].avg_speed = 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i < ARR_SIZ; i++)
    {
        for(o=0; o < SITE_COUNT; o++)
        {
            if(processedData[o].site_id_num == fileData[i].site_id_num)
            {
                // If Low Temp > fileData Temp
                if(processedData[o].lowest_temp > fileData[i].temperature)
                    processedData[o].lowest_temp = fileData[i].temperature;

                // If High Temp > fileData Temp
                if(processedData[o].highest_temp > fileData[i].temperature)
                    processedData[o].highest_temp = fileData[i].temperature;
            }

            // Get accumulated wind speed, process average later
            processedData[o].avg_speed += fileData[i].wind_speed;
        }
    }

    for(o=0; o< SITE_COUNT; o++)
    {
        // Get average wind speed
        processedData[o].avg_speed = processedData[o].avg_speed / DAY_RANGE;
    }

    int high_avg_wind = 0; // Average windspeed
    int high_var_temp = 0; // Variation of temperature
    int high_avg_wind_site_id = 0; // Site ID for Wind
    int high_var_temp_site_id = 0; // Site ID fir Temp

     // Temp variation for 3 sites
    int temperature_variation[SITE_COUNT];

    for(o=0; o< SITE_COUNT; o++)
    {
        // Determine site code for average wind speed, among 3 sites
        if(processedData[o].avg_speed > high_avg_wind)
        {       
            high_avg_wind = processedData[o].avg_speed;
            high_avg_wind_site_id = processedData[o].site_id_num;
        }

        // Get highest variation through subtraction        
        temperature_variation[o] = processedData[o].highest_temp - processedData[o].lowest_temp;

        // Determine site code for greatest variation, among 3 sites
        if(temperature_variation[o] > high_var_temp)
        {
            high_var_temp = temperature_variation[o];
            high_var_temp_site_id = processedData[o].site_id_num;
        }           
    }

    printf("The site with the highest average wind speed: %d\nThe site with the greatest variation in temperature is: %d\n",high_avg_wind_site_id,high_var_temp_site_id);

    // Close the file
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I set break points at the last loop to determine the data was being assigned correctly between the 3 sites, and it does appear to be measuring, but its returning site code 2001, when it should really be 3345 and 3819.

Here is the input of the data:

```
2001 10 11 30
3345 10 8 29
3819 10 17 27
2001 11 5 22
3345 11 5 23
3819 11 20 21
2001 12 18 25
3345 12 12 23
3819 12 22 21
2001 13 16 26
3345 13 14 24
3819 13 18 22
2001 14 14 26
3345 14 10 24
3819 14 15 22
2001 15 2 25
3345 15 9 22
3819 15 9 19
2001 16 14 22
3345 16 9 20
3819 16 12 18
```

Comment: Great code! Please do not post links to images of text. Please post the input as text into the question. Please post the output of your program you are getting currently. `its returning site code 2001, when it should really be 3345 and 3819.` - so where does it _print_ 2001? Which value is 2001? How one number 2001 should become two numbers 3345 and 3819?

Comment: I updated the thread with the problem data that needs to be processed. Somehow, high_avg_wind_site_id,high_var_temp_site_id come out with the same value of 2001, at the end of the program, via printf(), line 113, but after running the formulas in excel, their output in the program is incorrect.

Comment: `processedData[i].highest_temp = 50;` - well, when all values are _lower_ then 50, then... they will never be greater so initialize with very small (negative) value or initialize with the value of first element. The `processedData[o].avg_speed += fileData[i].wind_speed;` seems kind of strange that it isn't inside `if(processedData[o].site_id_num == fileData[i].site_id_num)`

Comment: Asjusting the position of the statement processedData[o].avg_speed += fileData[i].wind_speed; to the inner == statement resolved the wind_speed result. But, I re-initilized the processedData[i].highest_temp = 50 to processedData[i].highest_temp = fileData[i].temperature; but still returning the incorrect value.

Output is now:
The site with the greatest variation in temperature is: 2001

Comment: Cool, did you take a look at `lowest_temp`? `-50` is freezing

Comment: Yeah, lowest tempt is set to 0 (processedData[i].lowest_temp = 0;). If I make it higher or lower, it either changes from 2001, or 0. I also set it to the lowest temp identified from the data ( processedData[i].lowest_temp = 18;), but that still doesn't fix it.

Comment: `if(processedData[o].highest_temp > fileData[i].temperature)` should probably be `if(processedData[o].highest_temp < fileData[i].temperature)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems with your code are rather "typos" not big logic errors.

1. Process `processedData[o].avg_speed += fileData[i].wind_speed;` inside the `if(processedData[o].site_id_num == fileData[i].site_id_num)` so that it precesses current `SITE_COUNT`.
2. The highest value has to be initialized to very *low* value, not to very high. For example `processedData[i].lowest_temp = 999;
       processedData[i].highest_temp = -999;`.
3. The comparisions `if(processedData[o].lowest_temp > fileData[i].temperature)` `if(processedData[o].highest_temp > fileData[i].temperature)` are comparing the same way. One of them need to `<`.

After fixing those I was left with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SITE_COUNT 3 // 3 sites 2001,3345,3819
#define DAY_RANGE 7  // 7 days total, between site_ids

typedef struct
{
    int site_id_num;
    int day_of_month; // Day of the month (not used)
    int wind_speed;   
    int temperature;

} measured_data_t;

typedef struct
{
    int site_id_num;  // Storing the correct site ID
    int lowest_temp;  // Storing the lowest temp
    int highest_temp; // Storing the highest temp
    int avg_speed;    // Wind speed, for finding avg wind speed

} calculated_data;

// File pointer
FILE *fptr;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i=0, o=0; // Indexed for loops
    int ARR_SIZ = SITE_COUNT*DAY_RANGE;

    measured_data_t fileData[ARR_SIZ];          // Creates Struct array of 21, for 21 entries, 7 days for 3 sites 
    calculated_data processedData[SITE_COUNT];  // Created Struct array of  3, sites struct array

    // Open File
    if ((fptr = fopen("meteo.txt", "rt")) == NULL)
    {
        // Throw error if no file
        printf("\n Error opening data file");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0; i<ARR_SIZ; i++)
    {
        // Read lines from file, site_id, day, wind speed, temp
        int err = fscanf(fptr, "%d %d %d %d", &fileData[i].site_id_num, &fileData[i].day_of_month, &fileData[i].wind_speed, &fileData[i].temperature);
    if (err != 4) abort();
    }

    for (i=0; i<SITE_COUNT; i++)
    {
        // Assign defaults to processedData
        processedData[i].site_id_num = fileData[i*DAY_RANGE].site_id_num; // site_id_num position in array, 0..7..14
        processedData[i].lowest_temp = 999;
        processedData[i].highest_temp = -999;
        processedData[i].avg_speed = 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i < ARR_SIZ; i++)
    {
        for(o=0; o < SITE_COUNT; o++)
        {
            if(processedData[o].site_id_num == fileData[i].site_id_num)
            {
                // If Low Temp > fileData Temp
                if(processedData[o].lowest_temp > fileData[i].temperature)
                    processedData[o].lowest_temp = fileData[i].temperature;

                // If High Temp > fileData Temp
                if(processedData[o].highest_temp < fileData[i].temperature)
                    processedData[o].highest_temp = fileData[i].temperature;

            // Get accumulated wind speed, process average later
            processedData[o].avg_speed += fileData[i].wind_speed;
        }
        }
    }

    printf("%d %d\n", processedData[1].highest_temp, processedData[1].lowest_temp);

    for(o=0; o< SITE_COUNT; o++)
    {
        // Get average wind speed
        processedData[o].avg_speed = processedData[o].avg_speed / DAY_RANGE;
    }

    int high_avg_wind = 0; // Average windspeed
    int high_var_temp = 0; // Variation of temperature
    int high_avg_wind_site_id = 0; // Site ID for Wind
    int high_var_temp_site_id = 0; // Site ID fir Temp

     // Temp variation for 3 sites
    int temperature_variation[SITE_COUNT];

    for(o=0; o< SITE_COUNT; o++)
    {
        // Determine site code for average wind speed, among 3 sites
        if(processedData[o].avg_speed > high_avg_wind)
        {       
            high_avg_wind = processedData[o].avg_speed;
            high_avg_wind_site_id = processedData[o].site_id_num;
        }

        // Get highest variation through subtraction        
        temperature_variation[o] = processedData[o].highest_temp - processedData[o].lowest_temp;

        // Determine site code for greatest variation, among 3 sites
        if(temperature_variation[o] > high_var_temp)
        {
            high_var_temp = temperature_variation[o];
            high_var_temp_site_id = processedData[o].site_id_num;
        }           
    }

    printf("The site with the highest average wind speed: %d\nThe site with the greatest variation in temperature is: %d\n",high_avg_wind_site_id,high_var_temp_site_id);

    // Close the file
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Which seems to output:

```
The site with the highest average wind speed: 3819
The site with the greatest variation in temperature is: 3345
```

Comment: Ty, that nailed it, the conditional being backwards. I stopped at this problem earlier like deja vu, and then I went brain dead trying figure what I did wrong. The temperatures I initially had at higher values opposite of their terms, but had changed it back when I was backing up my data. But that damned corner bracket is what was throwing me off this whole time. You've done me a great deal of help, ty. I just needed some direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SITE_COUNT 3 // 3 sites 2001,3345,3819
#define DAY_RANGE 7  // 7 days total, between site_ids

typedef struct
{
    int site_id_num;
    int day_of_month; // Day of the month (not used)
    int wind_speed;
    int temperature;

} measured_data_t;

typedef struct
{
    int site_id_num;  // Storing the correct site ID
    int lowest_temp;  // Storing the lowest temp
    int highest_temp; // Storing the highest temp
    int avg_speed;    // Wind speed, for finding avg wind speed

} calculated_data;

// File pointer
FILE *fptr;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i=0, o=0; // Indexed for loops
    int ARR_SIZ = SITE_COUNT*DAY_RANGE;

    measured_data_t fileData[ARR_SIZ];          // Creates Struct array of 21, for 21 entries, 7 days for 3 sites
    calculated_data processedData[SITE_COUNT];  // Created Struct array of  3, sites struct array

    // Open File
    if ((fptr = fopen("meteo.txt", "rt")) == NULL)
    {
        // Throw error if no file
        printf("\n Error opening data file");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0; i<ARR_SIZ; i++)
    {
        // Read lines from file, site_id, day, wind speed, temp
        fscanf(fptr, "%d %d %d %d", &fileData[i].site_id_num, &fileData[i].day_of_month, &fileData[i].wind_speed, &fileData[i].temperature);
    }

    for (i=0; i<SITE_COUNT; i++)
    {
        // Assign defaults to processedData
        processedData[i].site_id_num = fileData[i*DAY_RANGE].site_id_num; // site_id_num position in array, 0..7..14
        processedData[i].lowest_temp = 9999;
        processedData[i].highest_temp = -9999;
        processedData[i].avg_speed = 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i < ARR_SIZ; i++)
    {
        for(o=0; o < SITE_COUNT; o++)
        {
            if(processedData[o].site_id_num == fileData[i].site_id_num)
            {
                // If Low Temp > fileData Temp
                if(processedData[o].lowest_temp > fileData[i].temperature)
                    processedData[o].lowest_temp = fileData[i].temperature;

                // If High Temp > fileData Temp
                if(processedData[o].highest_temp < fileData[i].temperature)
                    processedData[o].highest_temp = fileData[i].temperature;

                // Get accumulated wind speed, process average later
                processedData[o].avg_speed += fileData[i].wind_speed;
            }


        }
    }

    for(o=0; o< SITE_COUNT; o++)
    {
        // Get average wind speed
        processedData[o].avg_speed = processedData[o].avg_speed / DAY_RANGE;
    }

    int high_avg_wind = 0; // Average windspeed
    int high_var_temp = 0; // Variation of temperature
    int high_avg_wind_site_id = 0; // Site ID for Wind
    int high_var_temp_site_id = 0; // Site ID fir Temp

     // Temp variation for 3 sites
    int temperature_variation[SITE_COUNT];

    for(o=0; o< SITE_COUNT; o++)
    {
        // Determine site code for average wind speed, among 3 sites
        if(processedData[o].avg_speed > high_avg_wind)
        {
            high_avg_wind = processedData[o].avg_speed;
            high_avg_wind_site_id = processedData[o].site_id_num;
        }

        // Get highest variation through subtraction
        temperature_variation[o] = processedData[o].highest_temp - processedData[o].lowest_temp;

        // Determine site code for greatest variation, among 3 sites
        if(temperature_variation[o] > high_var_temp)
        {
            high_var_temp = temperature_variation[o];
            high_var_temp_site_id = processedData[o].site_id_num;
        }
    }

    printf("The site with the highest average wind speed: %d\nThe site with the greatest variation in temperature is: %d\n",high_avg_wind_site_id,high_var_temp_site_id);

    // Close the file
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Changes were:

1. Initialize a high value to lowest_temp and low value to highest_temp
2. Put the code inside the if clause

`// Get accumulated wind speed, process average later
                processedData[o].avg_speed += fileData[i].wind_speed;`

3. Changed condition to if(processedData[o].highest_temp `<` fileData[i].temperature)